# Why use <%Q in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've noticed that all of the rails APIs seem to use either of the following two notations for code nuggets in erb files;

```
<%Q ... %>
<%= ... %>
```

But seldom any mention of the vanilla

```
<% %>
```

for example, here;

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html

The book I've just read didn't cover the <%Q notation, so I'm assuming it's new. Is there any significance to the "Q" or is this just best practice now instead of just using <% ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<% %>` and `<%= %>` are features of erb. `<% %>` is used to embed some code in a template e.g. it would be used to embed an `if` statement

```
<% if @person.age > 18 %>
```

`<%= %>` is used to output a value within the template e.g

```
Name: <%= @person.name %>
```

`%Q` is a feature of the Ruby language and is not a Rails specific thing. As johnernaut writes it is used for double-quoted strings. e.g. instead of `puts "Say \"Hello\""` where you need to escape the double-quotes you can write `puts %Q(Say "Hello")`

However the `%Q` you're seeing in some of the Rails documentation don't seem to be a use of this Ruby feature. If you look at the actual [source of form_helper.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb) it doesn't have them so I'm thinking it's a quirk of the rdoc documentation tool.

---

**Update:** As Frederick as posted whilst I was writing the above, it looks like it is an [rdoc bug](https://github.com/rdoc/rdoc/issues/86).

Answer (score 3):

`<% %>` and `<%= %>` seem to be the common standard.  I believe `%Q` is used for double quoted strings:

```
>> %Q(Joe said: "Frank said: "#{what_frank_said}"")
=> "Joe said: "Frank said: "Hello!"""
```

Found via [relevant link](http://simpleror.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/q-q-w-w-x-r-s/).

Answer (score 2):

The <%Q  in the docs is the result of a bug in the rdoc tools being used, see [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-docs/browse_thread/thread/bc1ae76aa8179406)